# Move files to folders based on value in .csv file using .bat file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I need to move `.jpg` images from one folder to another using listing from CSV which changes periodically.

I need to move `.jpg` images from one folder into sub folders based on a value in a CSV file which periodically changes.
For example I have a folder called `D:\photos` which folder contains numbered sub folders i.e.

```
D:\photos\1000
D:\photos\1001
D:\photos\1002
```

Now in my folder  `D:\photos` There are three files named `a.jpg`, `b.jpb`, `c.jpb` where the output.csv looks like following

```
Output
1001
```

So as per CSV I have to move mention above files into d:\photos1001 which will be removed form actually folder.

Next in my folder `D:\photos` there are 3 files. `a.jpg`, `b.jpg` and `c.jpg`
and `output.csv` contains following information.

```
Output
1002
```

In this case I need to move the files `a.jpg`, `b.jpg` and `c.jpg`  into `D:\photos1002` then delete the files from `D:\photos`

Or another way I can change files in `1002_a.jpg` format too in the `D:\photos`folder.

Can anyone help me out with creating a `.bat` file that does this?

Comment: Do you want to move files like a.jpg to 1000, b.jpg to 1001 and c.jpg to 1002 folder or you want to move all files into a folder which name is written in .csv file e.g a.jpg, 1000 and in newline b.jpg, 1001

Comment: All the .jpgs in the folder need to move to the same folder (which is specified in the csv). Then they need to be deleted from the original folder as more will be placed there. The .csv will be updated with a new folder name and then all the new images moved to the new folder then deleted from the original folder

Answer (score 0):

Move all .csv file from one folder to another folder

@echo off

move E:\folder_from*csv*.* E:\folder_to